# Which transaction isolation Level should I use to prevent inserting data while selecting data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have three tables , `table A` and `TableB` and `Table C`.

I want to read data from `table A` and `join` it with `table B` and insert the result in `Table C`.
I don't want any other transactions can insert any records in `table A` while I'm `joining` `TablA` and `Table B.`

Which `isolation level` should I use? Is using `read committed isolation level` right or not?

Answer (score 3):

## You are asking the wrong question.

You shouldn't block inserts, why would you want to do that, specially in a concurrent environment like you describe? You'll only see blockage and deadlocks.

Instead you should ask `How can I ensure that the join between A and B is consistent` ? Meaning that the join will not see any record inserted during the join, without blocking said inserts. And the answer is use [SNAPSHOT ISOLATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

With SNAPSHOT ISOLATION each time you run the join you will see only rows that were already committed when the join started. Rows that were inserted (in A or B) after your join started are not visible. So the join is always consistent. Important thing is that you do not block inserts, and you won't deadlock either. Sounds too good to be true? Of course there is no free lunch, snapshot isolation has a cost, see [Row Versioning Resource Usage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175492%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

This is a good read on the topic: [Implementing Snapshot or Read Committed Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server: A Guide](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/).

Comment: is it going to lock the lines for deletion?

Comment: No. Deletes can proceed while the join runs, the join will return the deleted rows anyway (this is what row-versioning is all about, is all explained at length in the linked articles, I suggest you read them for a change).

Answer (score 1):

No, go for the Serializable option which is the best in your present scenario as they are use to prevent the user from adding new records being added to the table.

Comment: My program is multi thread and 10 threads can run concurrently and insert data. with this scenario I will have deadlock.

Comment: Then your chosen isolation is perfect.

Comment: You suppose I'm selecting data from table A and joining with Table B. and a threads inserts some records in Table A while I'm selecting. what will happen while I have `read Committed` isolation level?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Serializable from the MSDN

"A range lock is placed on the DataSet, preventing other users from updating or inserting rows into the dataset until the transaction is complete."

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.isolationlevel.aspx for details

Comment: The question is about tables (as in sql server tables), not client-side DataSets.

Comment: The categories of the question is asp.net and c#, thus he is accessing the DB using c#, these are the locking mechanism available from .Net, so the answer is appropriate

Comment: @Dan-o This answer _is_ about SQL Server, so it's indeed appropriate.

Comment: But using serializable may occurs deadlocks.isn't it?

Comment: Yes deadlock may occur. Are these tables high volume tables which will be updated concurrently

Comment: Yes they are high volume and will update concurrently. My program is multi thread and insert data concurrent. 10 to 15 threads can run concurrent

Comment: Must the data be update synchronously or would asynchronous work?

Comment: It depends on the scheduler operator adjust. can be synchronously or  not

Comment: So to avoid or at least minimize deadlock; process requests that must be synchronous immediately and ones which should't can be deferred to a queue and processed one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of blocking inserts, consider using snapshot isolation for reads. That way you get a point-in-time fully consistent and stable snapshot to read from. Concurrent DML does not disturb your reads.

If you need to block inserts, `SERIALIZABLE` is the minimum required level. You might well suffer from blocking and deadlocking. Therefore, I recommend snapshot isolation if you can at all use it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I will also go with **Serializable**.

```
Read uncommitted (the lowest level where transactions are isolated only enough to ensure that physically corrupt data is not read)
Read committed (Database Engine default level)
Repeatable read
Serializable (the highest level, where transactions are completely isolated from one another)*
```

Refer link which clearly show which will be used :-

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122%28v=sql.105%29.aspx